# find command doesn't print non pruned items

Tags: find

This command prints files/directories in the working directory having a basename starting with a period (a.k.a. hidden entries), non recursively.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '.*'
```

To print everything but those hidden entries I expected the following command to work … but nothing gets printed.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '.*' -prune -o -print
```

I ran those commands in my home directory where some non hidden entries exist like *Documents*, *Downloads* directories, some miscellaneous files etc which I expected to be printed.

Can someone explain me why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-prune` predicate prunes *directories* - in this case, `-name` will match the starting directory `.` and hence prune the whole tree.

What you want to do is simply negate the `-name` match:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.*'
```

or

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -name '.*'
```

Comment: So _find_ matches current special entry ".", but that dir name actually matches `-name .*` and as a result gets pruned, right?

Comment: @Stphane yes that's right... I think... I'm sure a more experienced contributor will correct me if that's not the case

Comment: Yes, that’s right; you can verify this by running `find . -maxdepth 1 -name '.*' -prune -print` (to prune and print) or even `find . -name '.*' -prune -print`.

Comment: Thank you, I simply forgot the special dot entry was part of the result.